# How to eliminate the space after paracol environment?

Tags: spacing, paracol

In the following example, there is space after the `paracol` environment. How do you smash the space after the environment so that the lower rule is snuggly fit against the `paracol` environment just like the upper rule is?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\backgroundcolor{c(1pt,0pt)(1pt,0pt)}[rgb]{0.85,0.95,1}
\newcommand*{\myrule}{\noindent\hfil\rule{0.8\textwidth}{.4pt}\hfil}

\begin{document}
    \myrule
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \sloppy
        \switchcolumn[0]*
        \blindduck[1]
        \switchcolumn[1]
        \blindduck[2]
    \end{paracol}
    \myrule
\end{document}
```

[image: good rule bad rule]

Comment: you are setting the rule as a paragraph and from your image the baseline to baseline spacing of the top and bottom rules look similar (the base spacing is slightly over sized because of the descender in `y`

Comment: Oh, right. There probably is space above the top rule, then, too. What is the descender in `y`? I think I'll just try to raise `\myrule` by `0.5\baselineskip`. Would that position it in the center of the (paragraph) text line?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hmm... not quite. `\rule[0.5\baselineskip]{0.8\textwidth}{.4pt}` raises it too high, so that the space between rule 1 and `paracol` is wider than between `paracol` and rule 2.

Comment: because you have boxed the text the it looks like the bottom rule is baselineskip below the coloured box, not baselineskip below the last baseline in the box, these are different because `y` in the last line has a tail "descender" below the baseline which moves the bottom of the colour box away from the baseline of the last row of text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{duckuments}

\backgroundcolor{c(1pt,0pt)(1pt,0pt)}[rgb]{0.85,0.95,1}
\newcommand*{\myrule}{\noindent\hfil\rule{0.8\textwidth}{.4pt}\hfil}

\begin{document}
    \myrule
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \sloppy
        \switchcolumn[0]*
        \blindduck[1]
        \switchcolumn[1]
        \blindduck[2]
    \end{paracol}
    \nointerlineskip\myrule
\end{document}
```